# Irreducibility of polynomials associated to binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $n \geq 2$.
Let $M_n$ be the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix with entries $\binom{l}{k}$ for $0 \leq l,k \leq n$ and $U_n=M_n + M_n^T$ and let $f_n(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $U_n$.

> Question 1: Is it true that either $f_n$ is irreducible or $f_n/x$ is irreducible (over $\mathbb{Q}$) for all $n$?

This is true for $n \leq 50$ and $f_n$ is irreducible except for $n$ in [2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 15] (but then $f_n(x)/x)$ is irreducible).

> Question 2: Is it true that the Galois group of $f_n(x)$ (or $f_n(x)/x$) is the full symmetric group when $f_n(x)$ is irreducible ($f_n(x)/x$ is irreducible)?

Question 2 has a positive answer for $n < 30$.

Comment: For $n=1$ I get $U_1 = \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 2\cr}$ and $f_n(x) = (x-3)(x-1)$ reducible, and $f_n(x)/x$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. I added the $n \geq 2$ assumption.

Comment: @Mare  A "random polynomial" (in a sense which can be made precise) over the rationals will be irreducible and will have the full symmetric group as Galois group. Nevertheless, for specific series of polynomials it can be hard to prove this. Is there special interest in your series of polynomials?

Comment: @PeterMueller I met the matrix $U_n$ as a Cartan matrix of some finite dimensional algebra. Also from a combinatorial viewpoint I think that $U_n$ looks interesting so I wonder whether there is a pattern behind this (for example when is $f_n$ reducible but $f_n/x$ irreducible?).

Comment: Do you understand when $x$ divides $f_n$, i. e., $\det M_n=0$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I have not yet figured when this happens or even if there are infinitely many $n$ such that this happens.

Comment: for what it worth, $M_n$ is the matrix of the operator $P(x)\to P(1+x)+\frac1{1-x}P(\frac{x}{1-x}) \pmod {x^{n+1}}$ in the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ (we take the terms up to $x^n$ in the corresponding power series).

Comment: Weird: $\det M_n=0$ for $n \in \{ 2,3,6,7,14,15 \}$. It is tempting to conjecture that the pattern is $n$ of the form $2^k-1$ or $2^k-2$, but $\det M_{30}$ and $\det M_{31} \neq 0$.